# Push objects of given array to mongodb document's array if specific key values are not present

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Lets say I have a document in mongo like

```
{
    name: "abc",
    manufacturer: "xyz",
    ...
    history: [
        {"condition": "new", "price": 150, "currency": "USD", "timestamp": "aaaaaaaaaaaa"}
    ]
}
```

Now with pymongo, I want to update the document that matches the filter(otherwise insert) and push each dictionary in history list if that dictionary does not exist there(in mongo doc's history array) with the following query

```
history = [
    {"condition": "new", "price": 150, "currency": "USD", "timestamp": "bbbbbbbbbbbb"},
    {"condition": "used", "price": 90, "currency": "USD", "timestamp": "cccccccccccc"},
]
item = {
    "name": "abcd",
    "manufacture": "xyz"
}
db.collection.update_one(filter, {"$set": item, "$addToSet": {"history": {"$each": history}}}, True)
```

Problem with above query is that I want to exclude the timestamp field(as it would always be unique eventually causing the dictionary to be pushed) from comparison of **$addToSet** which is not possible as per my research.

So I am trying to avoid doing two separate queries(to avoid performance issues as my collection contains millions of documents) with the an aggregation pipeline to which I am fairly new and would appreciate any help.
The updated document in mongodb should look like

```
{
    name: "abcd",
    manufacturer: "xyz",
    ...
    history: [
        {"condition": "new", "price": 150, "currency": "USD", "timestamp": "aaaaaaaaaaaa"},
        {"condition": "used", "price": 90, "currency": "USD", "timestamp": "cccccccccccc"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use update with pipeline, like this:

1. Add the new history and create a "clean" copy of the existing history - contains only a key that uses its properties without the timestamp and enables to compare.
2. Do the same for the new history - create a clean copy of keys and also add the keys to the current array.
3. use `$setDifference` to remove existing history keys from the new clean one.
4. `$merge` only the history object that left after the removal with the new history that have all the data.
5. clean the data and concatenate existing history with new one.

```
db.collection.update(
{name: "abcd", manufacturer: "xyz"},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      newHistory: [
        {condition: "new", price: 150, currency: "USD", timestamp: "bbbbbbbbbbbb"},
        {condition: "used", price: 90, currency: "USD", timestamp: "cccccccccccc"}
      ],
      oldHistoryClean: {
        $map: {
          input: "$history",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            key: 
            {$concat: ["$$item.condition", {$toString: "$$item.price"}, "$$item.currency"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      newHistoryClean: {
        $map: {
          input: "$newHistory",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            key: 
            {$concat: ["$$item.condition", {$toString: "$$item.price"}, "$$item.currency"]}
          }
        }
      },
      newHistory: {
        $map: {
          input: "$newHistory",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            condition: "$$item.condition",
            price: "$$item.price",
            currency: "$$item.currency",
            timestamp: "$$item.timestamp",
            key: 
            {$concat: ["$$item.condition", {$toString: "$$item.price"}, "$$item.currency"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      newHistoryClean: {$setDifference: ["$newHistoryClean", "$oldHistoryClean"]}
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      newHistoryClean: {
        $map: {
          input: "$newHistoryClean",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  "$newHistory",
                  {$indexOfArray: ["$newHistory.key", "$$this.key"]}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      newHistoryClean: {
        $map: {
          input: "$newHistoryClean",
          as: "item",
          in: {
            condition: "$$item.condition",
            price: "$$item.price",
            currency: "$$item.currency",
            timestamp: "$$item.timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      history: {$concatArrays: ["$history", "$newHistoryClean"]},
      name: 1,
      manufacturer: 1
    }
  }
],
{
  $upsert: true
})
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hWDk2h4FGLS)